# Getting Data from a json sub array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am looping through the following json. I get id and name fine, but when I do `json.templates[i].dailyemails.length` it always returns 0.

Here is my json:

```
{
   "templates":[
      {
         "id":"2c1d99d9b6b2fb417601d24c10c9b041a7d6f37b",
         "dailyemails":[
            "saaa@aa.com",
            "aaa.aaa@gmail.com"
         ],
         "name":"Registration Report"             
      },
      {
         "id":"7d7cc642ca13cc4a998cad364dfe8e623fd95ae3",
         "dailyemails":[
            "saaa@ss.com"
         ],
         "name":"Live Report"
      }

   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work just fine as seen in this [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zvta7/1/). Make sure that your actual JSON structure is the same as the one you have shown in your question.

Answer (score 1):

If this is JSON, that is a string, you have to parse it and work with a javascript object :

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

And then you may query `obj.templates[i].dailyemails`

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(data.templates,function(index,item){
    alert(item.dailyemails.length)
});
```

Sample : http://jsfiddle.net/JbF29/2/